# How can we check if the log output is using STDOUT in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, we can put this in development.rb if we are outputting the logs in the console:

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

So in Rails 5.x we can check if the log output is using STDOUT by using the code below:

```
# Returns true if the logger destination matches one of the sources which is STDOUT
ActiveSupport::Logger.logger_outputs_to?(Rails.logger, STDOUT)
```

Here's the documentation: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/492b9b413d3aa3a9bf3bf986ae25c7f90ec1ab62/activesupport/lib/active_support/logger.rb#L16

My question now is how can we check if the log output is using STDOUT in Rails 4? Because this script
*ActiveSupport::Logger.logger_outputs_to?* is not available in Rails 4.

Any ideas on this? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ActiveSupport::Logger.logger_outputs_to?() is not available in Rails 4, I just created a function.

```
def self.logger_stdout
   logdev = ::Rails.logger.instance_variable_get(:@logdev)
   logger_source = logdev.dev if logdev.respond_to?(:dev)
   sources = [$stdout]
   found = sources.any? { |source| source == logger_source }
end
```